# VS Code terminal color

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to change the final result of Powershell on VSCode to another color, I've tried to use `terminal.foreground` but it change the URL too (I just want the result "I love pizza" to lime green. Thank you guys so much

[image]

Comment: I don't see any url on your image. But maybe you should change back foreground after displaying `I love pizza`

Comment: what ` do you mean `"terminal.foreground"`? Is this some code in Python or settings in VSCode? Some terminals can use special codes in `print()` to change color for selected part of text - and there are even modules for this - i.e `bless`, `rich`

Comment: Let me know if that duplicate target doesn't answer your question @ChesterNguyen

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are called "ANSI Color Codes". They can be a bit hard to wrap your head around, but essentially you print a series of characters that change the style of output text, or reset the style.

A better approach for you would be to use a module that abstracts ANSI Color Codes into a more user-friendly API to style your text. Check out [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) and [rich](https://pypi.org/project/rich/).